# $2n\times 4$ $(0,1)$-matrix such that each row has two $0$'s and $1$'s and each column has $n$ $0$'s and $1$'s.

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways to fill a $2n\times 4$ $(0,1)$-matrix such that each row has two $0$'s and $1$'s and each column has $n$ $0$'s and $1$'s.

Equivalently, how many ways to fill a $2n\times 4$ $(-1,1)$-matrix such that each row and each column have zero sum.

By any chance, is there an asymptotic result for large $n$ ?

Answer (score 3):

There are six possibilities for each row.  The numbers of
$(0,0,1,1), (0,1,0,1), (0,1,1,0), (1,1,0,0), (1,0,1,0),$ and $(1,0,0,1)$, call these $n_1, \ldots, n_6$, must satisfy
$$ \eqalign{n_4 + n_5 + n_6 &= n\cr
 n_2+n_3+n_4 &=n\cr n_1+n_3+n_5 &=n\cr n_1+n_2+n_6&=n\cr}$$
Using some linear algebra one finds that $n_1 = n_4$, $n_2 = n_5$, $n_3 = n_6$, so the
number of solutions is just the number of ways to write
$n = n_1 + n_2 + n_3$ with nonnegative integers $n_1, n_2, n_3$.  And using generating functions, that is the coefficient of $x^n$ in the Maclaurin series of
$$\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k\right)^3 = \frac{1}{(1-x)^3}$$
which is $${n+2 \choose 2}$$

Comment: The latter formula also arises from "stars and bars": $\binom{n+3-1}{3-1}$

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thanks a lot for your answer. I found an article where an asymptotic result is shown and including my particular case. However it doe not match with your formula (when $n$ is large). Here it is: https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v12i1r29/pdf